# Bind Anonymous Type To Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I would like to bind an enumerable anonymous type to a repeater like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = myEnumerable.Select(x => new { foo = x.bar, ... });

    myRepeater.DataSource = obj;
    myRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

How do I access the `foo` property of `e.Item.DataItem` in `OnItemDataBound`?

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        myFunction(e.Item.DataItem.foo);
    }
}
```

I don't know what to cast `e.Item.DataItem` to, am I missing something? Is this possible without creating a strongly typed class?

I cannot directly bind `myEnumerable` to `myRepeater` because I have to manipulate it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the sequence of anonymous types to the repeater, but if you need to access that type from another method, it is time to define a proper class.

Anonymous types are useful in the narrow scope, when you do not *need* the type information to stick around*. In your case, you need it, so define a class.

---

*Technically, the type does of course stick around. The compiler is generating a class behind the scenes and giving it a name that as far as you are concerned is unspeakable. But that's happening under the covers, behind the scenes, and beneath the hood. Internally.